# Why do some questions have an orange background? And can I get a list of the newest questions for all my favorited tags combined?

Tags: support, design, user-interface, tag-filters, tag-watching

I've been using the Stack Overflow site for a while, but there are a number of things that confuse me:

1. Why are some questions in an orange background on the main page? (I can't work out any logic to it.)
2. How can I get a list of the newest questions for all my favorited tags combined?

Comment: Partial duplicate of : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll go point by point...

> Why are some questions in an orange background on the main page...

The posts with the orange background indicate that those questions contain tags that you have listed as your favorite tags.  [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean) for an in-depth explanation of all the colors on Stack Overflow and what they mean.

> How can I get a list of the newest questions for all my favorited tags combined

You are looking right at it!  On any view containing questions (ordered by date of course for "newest"), questions containing your favorited tags will be marked with an orange background.

Example -

[image]

One thing to note here is that we are talking about favorite tags - the system does not **only** show posts with your favorite tags - it simply marks them with the orange background.

If you would like to see questions only of a specific tag,
you can simply click on the tag itself - eg: [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook).  The link will take you to
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook` and from there you can again sort the questions by "newest" to get the most recent questions.  From this view only questions containing *additional* favorite tags will be highlighted, otherwise **all** the posts would be marked orange rendering the "highlighting" functionality redundant.

Comment: Neither of those works for me.
1) If I click on the link to one of my favourite tags, I get a list of all questions with that tag - only 20% or so are highlighted (I have no ignored tags)

Comment: 2) when I go to the main page, it doesnt filter by my favourite tags

Comment: The explanation for only a few posts to be highlighted when you are viewing questions by clicking on a tag is that it only highlights posts with your *other* favorited tags... Otherwise the whole screen would be orange and that wouldn't be very helpful would it? :)

Comment: OK thanks, I have marked this as the answer as things work as you describe. But in conclusion through, there is no view of the StackOverflow site that lists posts (by newest) that are EXCLUSIVELY just for your favourite tags - i.e. I still have to trawl through all the posts to find orange ones, or go through each of my tags separately.